# Handling Push Notification While App is Open

Tags: iphone, push-notification

I have my Push Notification running. It works. I receive a notification and use

```
application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:
```

to get the incoming data and then send the user to the necessary screen.

Problem is, if you are using the App and a notification is received, it jumps to the destination screen without giving any alert/sound/anything.

I could put an alert in `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:`, but then that alert would appear every time, not just when the app is running.

Ideas about how to handle this?

Comment: see this link you will get your answer-

Try it-

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554751/how-to-handle-push-notification-if-application-is-already-running

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend checking the applicationState property in UIApplication to determine if the app is running in the background or not.

Comment: applicationState is from iOS 4. What about iOS 3.x?