# Show push notification while the app is running in foreground using Swift

Tags: iphone, swift, push-notification

In my app I need to present push notification even while the user is using the app.
I can present it in when the app is in the background, but i can't do that when the user in using the app.
I searched and I saw that they use alert to present it like here: 
[Handling Push Notification While App is Open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170816/handling-push-notification-while-app-is-open)
but I don't want it present as alert, I want present it as notification, like this image but present it in the app

[image: push notification]

is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own custom `UIView` instead of showing 'Alert'.
You can handle animations manually.