# Push notification is not working when app is opened

Tags: iphone, ios7, push-notification

I have an issue with my app's push notification on ios 7, it works when app in back ground or remove it from dock. But push messages DO NOT work (not appearing) when the app screen comes to foreground.
But it was fine with iOS 6. Any change require in coding or storyboard settings?

Comment: Thanks for the answers.   I got an alternative solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554751/how-to-handle-push-notifications-if-the-application-is-already-running  .

Answer (score 0):

When PushNotification is arrive it calls `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method when app is in foreground.

And when your app is not in foreground it will send to Notification Center, and if user tap on  notification from notification center then it will call  `didReceiveRemoteNotification`method.

Answer (score 0):

**//According to Apple Push notification Document.**

Push notifications serve much the same purpose as a background application on a desktop system, but without the additional overhead. For an application that is not currently running—or, in the case of iOS, not running in the foreground—the notification occurs indirectly.

[Check Link :)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/WhatAreRemoteNotif.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH102-SW1)