# how to parse NSDictionary into NSUserDefaults IOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

In my application i want to display the remote notification in `UILabel`. So I'm trying pass the notification message form the "Appdelegate" to my storyboard its not working please tell me how to resolve this one.

My "Appdelegate" code:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo{

  NSString *messag = [[userInfo description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];

 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: messag forKey:@"message"];
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
 NSLog (@"message %@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"message"]);
 UIStoryboard *mainstoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
 personalnottypoliticalViewController *ringingVC = [mainstoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"notifymess"];

 [self.window setRootViewController: ringingVC];
 }
```

When i print my data its coming like:

```
message {
aps =     {
    alert = home;
    badge = 3;
    sound = "";
 };
}
```

in my viewcontroller i have used like this.

```
self.message.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"message"];
  NSLog (@"message %@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"message"]);
```

In the above data i need only the "Alert" value how to get the alert value and store into the data please tell me is that possible to do and how to achieve this one. I'm stack here for long not please give some ideas to achieve this one.

Thanks.

Comment: You are storing it like a JSON?

Comment: Look for some tutorials of using the base classes, an example for `NSDictionary`: http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/data-types/nsdictionary.html

Comment: @3r1d no i just need to store in a NSString data thats all

Comment: Log the value in the nsstring * message - the first line value , this will help us to find the data type of message ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `description` method creates a string representation of an object for logging purposes, but you wouldn't use it in that way to access the contents of the object.

From the Apple documentation -

> The userInfo dictionary contains the aps key whose value is another
>   dictionary. Although you should not need the information in the aps
>   dictionary, you can retrieve its contents using the following keys:
>
> **alert**—The value is either a string for the alert message or a
>   dictionary with two keys: body and show-view. The value of the body
>   key is a string containing the alert message and the value of the
>   show-view key is a Boolean. If the value of the show-view key is
>   false, the alert’s View button is not shown. The default is to show
>   the View button which, if the user taps it, launches the app.
>
> **badge** —A
>   number indicating the quantity of data items to download from the
>   provider. This number is to be displayed on the app icon. The absence
>   of a badge property indicates that any number currently badging the
>   icon should be removed.
>
> **sound** —The name of a sound file in the app
>   bundle to play as an alert sound. If “default” is specified, the
>   default sound should be played.

So, you can use the code from this answer - [How to handle push notifications if the application is already running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554751/how-to-handle-push-notifications-if-the-application-is-already-running)

```
NSDictionary *aps=(NSDictionary *)[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];

NSString *message;

id alert = [aps objectForKey:@"alert"];
if ([alert isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
   message = alert;
} else if ([alert isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
   message = [alert objectForKey:@"body"];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi try using this code

NSDictionary *dict=userInfo;

NSString *messag=[[[dict objectForKey:@"message"]objectForKey:@"aps"]objectForKey:@"alert"];