# Push notification style when app is in foreground

Tags: ios, push-notification, uialertview

When I'm testing my iOS app, I set my notification style preferences to banner style. This works when my app IS NOT in foreground (either in background or closed). However, when the app IS in foreground, the notifications appear as `UIAlertView`.

Is this by design from Apple? Or perhaps I'm missing some setting I can apply?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` inside your `AppDelegate.m`. This way you can handle the notification the way you want. Sometimes its not needed to show anything inside an `UIAlertView` but you want to update specific `UILabels` or what ever. You also get a `userInfo` where you can get more specific information about your `Push`. You can also identify in which mode you're at the moment:

```
if ( application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive 
     || application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground  ) {

} else {

}
```

[**The Documentation says:**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)

> Use this method to process incoming remote notifications for your app.
>   Unlike the application:didReceiveRemoteNotification: method, which is
>   called only when your app is running in the foreground, the system
>   calls this method when your app is running in the foreground or
>   background. In addition, if you enabled the remote notifications
>   background mode, the system launches your app (or wakes it from the
>   suspended state) and puts it in the background state when a push
>   notification arrives. However, the system does not automatically
>   launch your app if the user has force-quit it. In that situation, the
>   user must relaunch your app or restart the device before the system
>   attempts to launch your app automatically again.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but how does that help me set the notification to display as a banner instead of `UIAlertView`, if that's at all possible?

Comment: Have a look at this one. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1554831/1141395. It is up to you how the notification will be handled. Have you just tried it and the `UIAlertView` did appear anyway?

Comment: OK, the answer you pointed to suggests that I can display `UIAlertView` myself. But it's already displaying an alert view, while I would prefer a banner style - just like it does when the app is not in foreground. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

"**When the app is in foreground, the notifications appear as UIAlertView.**"

It should not be, unless, you have wrote to show an alert in your ApDelegate's `didReceiveRemoteNotification:` method. When you receive a push notification that method will get called.

If you wants to show some toast notification (While app is in Foreground) than you can check this. 
[Get push notification while App in foreground iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872088/get-push-notification-while-app-in-foreground-ios)